# How to set the value of a form field to a value from a JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, forms

I have a JSON that looks like that: (partial example)

```
[{"field_name":"birth_date",
  "serial_num":"1",
  "is_required":"true",
  "get_possible_values_from":"null",
  "gui_description":"Birth Date",
  "value":"1990-11-06"},

 {"field_name":"city",
  "serial_num":"2",
  "is_required":"true",
  "get_possible_values_from":"null",
  "gui_description":"City",
  "value":"New York"}]
```

I have the HTML form, and I want the value of each field to be the field's "value" from the JSON.
But when I do this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="field in fields | orderBy: 'serial_num'">
<div data-ng-show="field.fields_group==0">
    <div data-ng-show="field.get_possible_values_from=='null'">
    <!-- mark obligated fields with * -->
        <span data-ng-show="field.is_required=='true'">*</span>
        {{field.gui_description}}:
        <div align="center">
            <input type="text" value="field.value" id="field.gui_description">
        </div>
  </div>
```

It shows the value as "field.value", instead of the actual value.

How can I set the value to be the actual value from the JSON..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try bellow

```
<input type="text" value="{{field.value}}" id="field.gui_description"/>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18182/)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thakns for your response, but It was not a guess, I would better try it and then write the answer, if you see there is a demo as well, and What I think OP know the way I'm doing it. OP have already used `{{field.gui_description}}` so he/she would be knowing what this operator means. BTW

Answer (score 1):

You should use `data-ng-value` like:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-value="field.value">
```

In your code `value="field.values"` is not using any kind of AngularJS binding, so the exact value will be used in html.

Comment: Thanx! I have another attribute in the JSON, called "data", to save the user input, but when I update that line to <input type="text" data-ng-value="field.value" id="field.gui_description" data-ng-model="field.data"> 
the default value doesnt work.. any ideas why?

Comment: @ArbelA why would you expect the default value to work? You have added `data-ng-model` which means that the whole tag will bind to `field.data` which doesn't contains a field like `field.value`. It breaks the binding for value too.

Comment: So how can I bind it to "data" to save the input value, and also show a default value..?
(using   value="{{field.value}}"   doesn't work)